# problem with AJAX encoding , none English words are unreadable

Tags: json, ajax, encoding

hello everyone for a project i use Ajax to call data from server to client
everything is well except encoding of json file
for example here is json file which i think theres a problem with encoding :

```
"id":"595","company":"\u0645\u0627\u0647\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u06cc\u0631\u062c\u0627\u0646"
```

as you see English words are well , but none English words are not readable

so what should i do ?
could someone please help me ?

Comment: It means that all non-ASCII characters are escaped. I don't speak _ajax/java_ but note the [`ensure_ascii` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump). Something alike was used while creating jour JSON file. HTH.

Comment: then what should i do to force use utf -8 ?

Comment: You could get more/better response if you  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].